# Set a value to an input type=“date” on mobile Safari using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, safari

I have a JavaScript function that sets the value of `<input type="date"/>` (Not `datetime`) from a popup calendar to support browsers that don't have a date picker. When the input is clicked, the calendar pops up and allows dates to be selected.

To prevent the user from typing arbitrary information (although it is validated server side anyway) the field is also read only, which also helps instruct them to use the calendar. All these features rely on JS, so if it is disabled, the date field works as usual.

This works great in every browser except Safari on an iPad/iPhone, which sets the value to nothing. The current format of the date is `dd/mm/yyyy`. Is there a specific format Safari expects?

Comment: Your approach will create usability issues. If the platform doesn't provide any support, users aren't going to expect it to so just let them type into the field. You must validate the value anyway.

Comment: Most don't consider [accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/mobile/) when creating popups, you may be making life harder (or impossible) for some users.

Comment: I don't know why you are criticizing something you have never seen or used so much. Why not just help answer the question instead of try to rip it apart...

Comment: Just a suggestion (since you haven't shown any code), according to the [W3C HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)), the value must be in the format [yyyy-mm-dd](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/infrastructure.html#valid-date-string). I'm not trying to "rip it apart", just making suggestions, which is what comments are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I went with (as I could not get Safari to recognize any input) was to change the type to text after attaching all the JavaScript hooks and adding the readonly attribute. This allowed Safari to function just like all other browsers, but still work when JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a date field, use an image as a background to a button and set a hidden field with that date.